# Magento create shipment with tracking number programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

From a specific order I want to create shipment of that order and also allot tracking number to it programmatically.
Please help .
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question was just for knowledge sharing purpose .

One can understand some points from [Ref_Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799498/magento-create-partial-invoice-programmatically)

```
// $order_id = Order ID
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

if($_order->canShip())
{           
    $shipmentId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create($_order->getIncrementId(), $itemsarray ,'your_comment' ,false,1);
    echo $shipmentId;   // Outputs Shipment Increment Number
    $trackmodel = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')
    ->addTrack($shipmentId,'your_shipping_carrier_code','your_shipping_carrier_title','carrier_tracking_number');
}
```

`$itemsarray` = format explained here [Ref_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799498/magento-create-partial-invoice-programmatically)

Thats it !
A simple code snippet .
Hope it helps someone .

Comment: Note that $shipmentId is actually the Shipment Increment Id

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct and worked for me on CE 1.9, but I wanted to expand on it.

You don't need to bother with the `$itemsQty` parameter, you can pass an empty `array()`, or leave it out altogether. It's an optional parameter, and the method `prepareShipment()` in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Service\Order.php` will check for that data and perform a lookup if necessary.

If you want to include the tracking number in the shipment email, make sure you add the tracking first and then use `Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->sendInfo($shipmentIncrementId)`.

Code Snippet:

```
        $shipmentApi = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api');

        //pass false for email, unless you want Magento to send the shipment email without any tracking info
        //could also be written as $shipmentIncrementId = $shipmentApi->create($order->getIncrementId());
        $shipmentIncrementId = $shipmentApi->create($order->getIncrementId(), array(), '' , false, 0); 

        //add tracking info ($shippingCarrier is case sensitive)
        $shipmentApi->addTrack($shipmentIncrementId, $shippingCarrier, $shippingTitle, $trackingNumber);

        //send shipment email with tracking info
        $shipmentApi->sendInfo($shipmentIncrementId);
```

create() method signature:

```
public function create($orderIncrementId, $itemsQty = array(), $comment = null, 
                                               $email = false, $includeComment = false)
```

See `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Api.php` for all methods.